# Storing Char and Int in an array and writing it to a Text File

Tags: arrays, c, text-files, function-call, undefined-symbol

I am trying to store char and int to the array 'employeeInfo' and write it to the text box 'KMARTEXT.txt'.

i am not sure on how to store in an array then to a text file.

I had the error in the addEmployee function.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h> // TEXT COLOR
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #define g gotoxy
 #define p printf
 #define s scanf
 #define cp cprintf
 struct employeeInfo{ 
char employeeName[20];
int employeeBirthdate;
char employeeAddress[30];
int employeePhone;
};

FILE *pf, *tf, *temp;
int x, y;

int main(){
clrscr();
splash();
pickFunction();
getch();
}

splash(){
clrscr();
for(x=1;x<=80;x++){
        g(x,1); p("%c",178); delay(20);
    }
    for(y=2;y<=24;y++){
        g(80,y); p("%c",178); delay(20);
    }
    for(x=79;x>=1;x--){
        g(x,24); p("%c",178); delay(20);
    }
    for(y=23;y>=2;y--){
        g(1,y); p("%c",178); delay(20);
    }
textcolor(WHITE);
g(27,7); cp(" KMAR Employee Login System ");
}

pickFunction(){
char chosenOperation;
textcolor(WHITE);
g(31,11); cp("A.) Login");
g(31,12); cp("B.) Add Employee");
g(31,13); cp("C.) Delete Employee");
g(31,14); cp("D.) Search Employee");
g(31,15); cp("E.) Exit");
g(32,17); cp("Choose Operation: "); s("%s",&chosenOperation);

    switch(chosenOperation){
    case 'a': case 'A': loginEmployee(); break; /* Add/write to file function */
    case 'b': case 'B': addEmployee(); break; /* Search by num/string function */
    case 'c': case 'C': deleteEmployee(); break;
    case 'd': case 'D': searchEmployee(); break;
    case 'e': case 'E': exit(0); break;
    default: 
        textcolor(YELLOW);
        g(22,20); cp("Invalid Option! Press ENTER to go back..");
        getch();
        clrscr();
        main();
}
}

addEmployee(){
struct employeeInfo pck;
clrscr();
pf = fopen("KMARTEXT.txt", "w");

if(pf == NULL)
{
    /* File not created hence exit */
    printf("Unable to create file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
g(31,12);
printf("Enter Employee Name: \n");
fgets(employeeInfo, employeeName, stdin);
fputs(employeeInfo, pf);
fclose(pf);
 return 0;
}
```

the error was **Undefined symbol employeeInfo in function addEmployee**

**Undefined symbol employeeName in function addEmployee**

Comment: The "undefined symbol" messages are because those are not variables in their own right, but `struct` members. Asides: a) excuse me for saying but you seem to be using coding material that is out of date by decades. We don't define functions like that now. b) Abbreviating the names of library functions, so the reader must go and look for what they mean is unhelpful, please search/replace before posting.

Comment: The `fgets(employeeInfo, employeeName, stdin);` is passing incorrect argument types anyway.

Comment: regarding: `  default: 
        textcolor(YELLOW);
        g(22,20); cp("Invalid Option! Press ENTER to go back..");
        getch();
        clrscr();
        main();`   This will not properly setup for a call to `main()`  Strongly suggest implementing a `for()` or `while()` loop rather than calling `main()`

Answer (score 1):

Your employeeinfo is a structure *tag*, not an actual instance of the struct. In other words, you described what such a structure contains, but you didn't create one.

You might want to review how to define structures: [struct](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In `addEmployee`, you want:

```
fgets(pck.employeeName, sizeof pck.employeeName, stdin);
fputs(pck.employeeName, pf);
```